# Rust how to convert from array to std::raw:::Slice

Tags: rust, unsafe

`std::raw::Slice` is defined as :

```
pub struct Slice<T> {
    pub data: *const T,
    pub len: uint,
}
```

I am trying something like this:

```
use std::raw::Slice as RawSlice;
let a = [1i,2,3,4];
let s : RawSlice<int>= RawSlice{data: a as *const int, 
        len : a.len()};
```

This doesn't compile. `error: non-scalar cast: [int, ..4] as *const int`. I am basically unable to figure out how to get a pointer to the beginning of the array.

A similar concern is: how to convert from [int] to *const int?

Comment: Why do you need a `raw::Slice` to begin with? Are you perhaps looking for an ordinary slice `&[int]`?

Comment: I was exploring if I could implement some traits for slices. But &[int] doesn't happen to be a Sized type. Hence, one can't implement traits for them. Then, I thought of this alternative. Was just exploring ideas.

Comment: `&[T]` is sized. It's `[T]` that is unsized.

Comment: Ohk, so can i implement traits for &[T] ?

Comment: In general, you just do it. If you get a specific error message when trying to implement a specific trait, please post that as a new question (this one's so old it probably won't get any more attention).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can take a pointer to the first element of the array and convert it:

```
&a[0] as *const int
```

Comment: This works most of the time, but if you have an empty slice (which still points to a valid pointer), it'll fail bounds checks and panic.

Comment: @Undeterminant I don't know enough about Rust to follow this. If the slice is empty, what should it be as a raw pointer?